# Connect Remote Database using Selenium Webdriver and run Test Cases from local machine through eclipse

Tags: java, .htaccess, selenium-webdriver

I am using **selenium web driver java built**, the editor is **eclipse**. For testing one of our websites I am using Data-driven testing by fetching data from MySQL database.

I dumped the development server database to my local machine and installed that dumped data in my machine xampp and able to connect to the database and proceed through the testing process.

To connect to my local machine database I am using this connection string

```
String url1 ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename";           
String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
Class.forName(dbClass).newInstance();
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url1, "root", "");
Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
```

Now I need to connect to our original development server database which is in remote server.

I have tried  this as connection string to connect remote machine

```
 String url1 ="jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.129:3306/test";
 String dbClass ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
 Class.forName(dbClass).newInstance();
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url1, "root","root");
```

but not able to connect to the remote machine database.

Following error is showing:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Can anyone suggest me **what changes are needed to be done in the connection string to connect the remote server database which is ht access protected**?

And how I can run my test cases from my local machine while connecting to the remote server database.

Please provide some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify machine's IP address, port and database name in the connection string. So try something like

```
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.53306/myDB";
DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "username", "password");
```

And your tests should work the same way as before, you are just connectng to the different machine which can be more time consuming (e.g. queries can take more time) but that's the only difference.

Comment: to open our remote server database , we have to provide ht access username and password , can you tell me how  to pass that information in the connection string.

Comment: The same you did it while connection to localhost. I also edited my answer to reflect that

Comment: Thank you for your reply , but what i am talking about is slightly different from what u understood. 

I am talking about Htaccess username and password , which is required to  given when we open our remote database and that username and password is different from database username and password.

Through this
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.53306/myDB";
DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "username", "password");

we can connect to database but before connecting to database we have to clear the ht access, how to do that.

Comment: John, your question is not related to webdriver. Search the forum for "htaccess authentication using java". There is a tag as well for "htaccess" questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize data driven capability provided by one of the [selenium testing-frameworks](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp#testing-frameworks) - [ISFW](http://blog.infostretch.com/isfw-faq) where you can specify data base query to provide test data.
For example:

```
@IsDataProvider(sqlQuery="select query")
@Test
public void testSomething(Map<String, String> testdata){
  //use query col as key testdata.get("colName")
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a jar file to connect to the database

```
jar: mysql-connector-java
```